# How to put the following J_C Hamiltonian in the matrix form

Tags: differential-equations, matrix

I am trying to get the Matrix form of the following Hamiltonian for a finite dimension of $\hat a$
$$H = wc{\hat a^\dagger}\hat a + wa{{{{\hat \sigma }_z}} \over 2} + g({\hat \sigma _ - }{\hat a^\dagger} + \hat a{\hat \sigma _ + }),$$
where ${\hat a^\dagger}, \hat a$ are the creation and annihilation operators, ${\hat \sigma +}, {\hat \sigma _ - }$ are rising and lowring operators.

I used the following Mathematica code but I am not sure:

```
σx = PauliMatrix[1]; σy = PauliMatrix[2];    σz =
  PauliMatrix[3];     σI = IdentityMatrix[2];
σp = 1/2 (σx + I*σy);

dim = 2;

Idim[dim_] := IdentityMatrix[dim, SparseArray];

a[dim_] := 
 KroneckerProduct[Idim[2], 
  SparseArray[{Band[{1, 2}] -> Sqrt[Range[dim - 1]]}, {dim, dim}]]
adag[dim_] := ConjugateTranspose[a[dim]]
nhat[dim_] := ConjugateTranspose[a[dim]].a[dim];

sigmap[dim_] := KroneckerProduct[σp, Idim[dim]]
sigman[dim_] := ConjugateTranspose[sigmap[dim]]

HHc = ωc nhat[dim];
HHa = 1/2 ωa sigmap[dim].sigman[dim];
HHac = g (adag[dim].sigman[dim] + a[dim].sigmap[dim]);

HJC = HHa + HHc + HHac;
MatrixForm[HJC]
```

Comment: Can you, please, provide the Mathematica code you have used to try to answer this question? As it is now, this does nothing seem like a question. About the Mathematica software.

Comment: @CATrevillian Thank you for the advice, I will edit my question.

Comment: I discuss the Jaynes–Cummings model in Section 5.3 of [my book](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.7050), albeit using a position/momentum representation instead of creation/annihilation.

Comment: @Roman It is really a great book that helped me in solving a lot of problems. But I couldn't how do I set dim = 2 in your code as in my case. Can you please show me the parameter values that I should set?

Comment: Not correct. $\hat{\sigma}_{\pm}$ and $\{\hat{a},\hat{a}^\dagger\}$ act  in different Hilbert spaces. You cannot just multiply them. You need a direct product.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your Hamiltonian. What are you trying to compute? Time-dependent states? Energy eigenstates? To get interesting dynamics you'll probably have to increase your `dim` a bit.

Comment: @yarchik that's precisely what he's doing with the `KroneckerProduct`: each operator as presented already acts in the full (combined) Hilbert space. For example, `sigmap[dim]` acts as $\hat{\sigma}_+$ in the spin space and acts trivially in the excitation space. A product like `adag[dim].sigman[dim]` is then correct, because both component operators are represented in the combined Hilbert space.

Comment: @Roman Probably you are right, but it's inefficient.

Comment: @Roman  I put `dim=2` just as an example. Exactly, I want to calculate the time-dependent spectrum for a specific `dim`

Comment: What's a time-dependent spectrum? Time and spectrum (energy) are canonically conjugate variables and you can't have both.

Comment: Sorry, thank you for the clarification, I mean time-dependent states.